# Query that only includes objects that don't have a particular element empty - App Engine

Tags: database, google-app-engine, filter

Can I make a query that only includes objects that don't have a particular element empty in Google App Engine database?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by empty? That the value is an empty string? Undefined? Or the property is inexistent?

Answer (score 0):

```
non_empty_profile= Profile.all().filter('user !=',None)
```

Comment: `.filter('user >', None)` is more efficient and has the same effect, since `None` sorts lower than all other elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible to filter for property values on entities where that property exists. So if you want entities where `name` has any value, including `None`, you can do this:

`query.filter('name >=' None)`

If you want to fetch all values except `None`, do this:

`query.filter('name >' None)`

To fetch all values except an empty string:

`query.filter('name !=', '')`